# Flex item using percent width containing thumbnail and div with text won't resize with its parent?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

**My problem:**

Code details below.

When I render just the card thumbnail, I get the behavior that I need, which is: each card is **always** `25%` of the width.

[image]

But when I add the card titles, I get this other behavior. Somehow the cards don't resize to fit the `25%` width anymore.

[image]

This is the behavior I need (see GIF below):

It works when I remove this part of the code (see below). But I really need this part of the code. I can't remove it.

```
const Layout_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const Content_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 1 1 850px;                  // WILL SHRINK AND GROW WHEN NECESSARY
  border: 1px dotted silver;
`;

const SideBar_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted silver;
`;
```

[image]

**QUESTION**

How can I get the cards with the titles to resize just like the thumbnail does?

Code SandBox with the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-microservice-76w79

---

My main content is max 1200px and it's centered by these components:

```
const Container_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;            // THIS WILL CENTER
`;

const MaxWidth_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 1 1200px;                   // IT WILL SHRINK WHEN WIDTH IS LOWER THAN 1200
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
`;
```

These components are used to split my layout between content and side bar.

```
const Layout_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const Content_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 1 1 850px;                  // WILL SHRINK AND GROW WHEN NECESSARY
  border: 1px dotted silver;
`;

const SideBar_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 350px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  border: 1px dotted silver;
`;
```

Now I need to render inside `Content_DIV` a carousel component that should have `overflow: hidden` and render card items that are `25%` of its width, by using `flex: 0 0 25%`.

```
const Carousel_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;                    // OVERFLOW SHOULD BE HIDDEN
`;

const FlexContainer_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;                       // THIS IS A FLEX CONTAINER (ITEMS WILL BE IN A SINGLE ROW)
`;

const FlexItem_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 25%;                       // EACH ITEM SHOULD BE 25% (ONLY 4 ITEMS WILL BE VISIBLE)
`;
```

And these are the components I'm using for the card items (each card will render inside a `FlexItem_DIV` ):

```
const CardContainer_DIV = styled.div`

`;

const AspectRatio_DIV = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
`;

const Thumbnail_DIV = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Thumbnail_IMG = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
`;

const CardTitle_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.1em;
`;
```

This is the full component structure:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    thumbnailItems.push(
      <FlexItem_DIV key={i}>
        <CardContainer_DIV>
          <AspectRatio_DIV>
            <Thumbnail_DIV>
              <Thumbnail_IMG src={"http://lorempixel.com/640/480/abstract"} />
            </Thumbnail_DIV>
          </AspectRatio_DIV>
          <CardTitle_DIV>
            Commodi id suscipit voluptate sint cumque similique et magni
          </CardTitle_DIV>
        </CardContainer_DIV>
      </FlexItem_DIV>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container_DIV>
      <MaxWidth_DIV>
        <Layout_DIV>
          <Content_DIV>
            <Carousel_DIV>
              <FlexContainer_DIV>{thumbnailItems}</FlexContainer_DIV>
            </Carousel_DIV>
          </Content_DIV>
          <SideBar_DIV>I am SideBar</SideBar_DIV>
        </Layout_DIV>
      </MaxWidth_DIV>
    </Container_DIV>
  );
```

**UPDATE WITH EXTRA INFO**

From further testing, it seems that when I add the `CardTitle_DIV`, it's like the `FlexItem_DIV` starts treating the `25%` as `25%` of the full `window.innerWidth` instead of the `25%` of the `Content_DIV` where it's located.

Code SandBox with the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-microservice-76w79

Comment: I think you're stumbling onto the [flex minimum size algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140). Add `min-width: 0` to `const Content_DIV = styled.div`. And try switching the `font-size` in `const CardTitle_DIV = styled.div` from 22px to, let's say, `2vw`.