# Problem with nested flex containers. Inner container's item is not respecting its parent's width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-sanne-mdh5s

I'll try to reproduce it here with a minimal example that I've built on CodeSandbox.

I've been having some troubles while keeping the proper `width` for a the items of a nested `flex` container. What I mean by nested, is that this (inner) `flex` container lives inside an another (outer) `flex` container.

Alright, I have an outer `flex` container that splits my layout into 2 columns. One column is for the **main content** and one for a **side bar**.

```
const Layout_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;                    // THIS IS THE OUTER FLEX CONTAINER
`;

const Content_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 1 1 1000px;                 // THIS WILL EXPAND OR SHRINK WHEN NECESSARY
`;

const SideBar_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 200px;                  // THIS RENDERS A SIDE BAR OF WIDTH 200px
`;
```

And inside that `Content_DIV` I have a carousel with `overflow-hidden` and I need to render some product cards inside of it.

```
const Carousel_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const FlexContainer_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;                            // THIS IS THE INNER FLEX CONTAINER
`;

const FlexItem_DIV = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 25%;
`;
```

And inside those `FlexItem_DIV` I will render the product cards. With a `thumbnail` and a `title`. Since, the `FlexItem_DIV` has `flex: 0 0 25%`, only 4 cards should be visible at a time, and they should all fit inside `Content_DIV`

When I'm rendering only the thumbnails, everything works fine and I get the intended behavior. Nice!

[image]

But as soon as I add the product title, that behavior changes completely and everything gets messed up. Nothing fits anymore.

[image]

The only difference in those two GIFs above is the presence of the title. Literally nothing else was changed.

**What I've tried:**

- Lots of things. Including giving a `px` width for the flex item, instead of `25%`
- I've also tried working with the `white-space: wrap` for the title, but nothing works.

**What I think is causing this:**

This seems to be caused by the presence of the outer `flex` container. I mean, that one that handles the split of the columns for the `Content_DIV` and `SideBar_DIV`.

Cause when I get rid of it (the outer `flex` container), then I get the desired behavior. See now that the `SideBar` is rendering below the Carousel and not on the right side anymore. Of course, I need it to be on the side and not below. That's why this solution does not work for me. But just to illustrate, I'll do this:

```
const Layout_DIV = styled.div`
  /* display: flex; */              <---- I'VE COMMENTED THIS LINE
`;
```

While this works as far as shrinking the title div and fitting everything on the screen, I really need the outer flex container so I can have the `SideBar` on the side, and not below.

[image]

**PS:** Tested both on Chrome and Firefox.

**QUESTION**

Has anyone seen this problem before? I need the behavior from the 1st GIF, but with the product titles present.

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-sanne-mdh5s

**EXTRA**

I don't think this is relevant for the issue, but this is the code of the product card that renders inside `FlexItem_DIV`:

```
const CardContainer_DIV = styled.div``;

const AspectRatio_DIV = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
`;

const Thumbnail_DIV = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Thumbnail_IMG = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
`;

const CardTitle_DIV = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.1em;
`;
```

Comment: Same as your [previous question today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63614638/3597276), no? See my explanation in the comments there.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin yes! This was an attempt to make the question more clear. This almost drove me crazy today. Worst thing I've ever had to debug. The `min-width` did the trick. I think this question ended up better than the other one. I'll delete the other.

Comment: I think you're stumbling onto the [flex minimum size algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276). Add `min-width: 0` to `const Content_DIV = styled.div`. And try switching the `font-size` in `const CardTitle_DIV = styled.div` from `22px` to, let's say, `2vw`.

Comment: That's it. I could make it work by setting `min-width: 0` to `Content_DIV`, which is the outer `flex` item. Then it fixed the `width` for the nested `flex` container's items. Thanks a lot, man. This trick feels like "dark-magic", though. They should "fix" this somehow, or add a property with a more friendly name that allows us to work with that solution more easily. Thanks again.

Comment: You're not alone. See the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383437/3597276), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43312314/3597276) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/3597276).

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin This is surreal... horrible pitfall to run into. Do you know if this solution works fine across browsers? The `min-width: 0` "trick" ?

Comment: Yep. Probably millions of hours wasted trying to figure this one out. As one [commenter mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38383437/3597276), this "feature" should be disclosed front and center in flex documentation.